# whats wrong in below query Select CONVERT(xml,'<x>' + Replace(A.name,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' ) as xDim from Erecharge;

Tags: mysql

I want to convert string to xml column ..
I used below query for that :

```
 Select CONVERT(xml,'<x>' + Replace(A.name,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' ) as xDim from Erecharge;
```

but it shows error of incorrect sql syntax.. 
I want to know whats wrong in above query

I also tried this:

```
 Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(A.name,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim from Erecharge;
```

Comment: Please check the error message again. It should mention the exact spot where the typo is.

Comment: I got this error:  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'XML) as xDim from Erecharge' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'XML) as xDim from Erecharge'`

This means that `XML` is incorrect in a expression like this:

```
CAST('foo' AS XML)
```

As per [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert), the values allowed for `CAST` type do not include `XML`.

Additionally, using the [`+` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_plus) on strings is just a convoluted way to render zero:

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' + 'b';
+-----------+
| 'a' + 'b' |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. MySQL has [XML Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html) but it doesn't have [XML data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html). If you just want to produce a string that happens to contain XML code then you need to [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('<date>', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '</date>') AS foo;
+----------------------------------+
| foo                              |
+----------------------------------+
| <date>2018-10-12 11:44:29</date> |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

... but of course you still need to ensure that angle brackets and similar stuff don't break the XML. [`CDATA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) may help. (No idea about XML functions, I'm not familiar with them.)